# Consume multiple items with generator.send() in one line

Tags: python, generator

Is there an idiom to directly feed a list/generator to a generator?

```
lst = [1, 2, 3]
it = my_gen()
next(it)
# can do without i ?
for i in lst:
  it.send(i)
```

UPD:
Is it possible to chain lst with it in one line, removing `for` and `i` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is a way to do that using [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=map#map) and [`deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=collections#collections.deque) to consume the iterator (explanation here: [itertools consume recipie](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes))
:

```
from collections import deque

def my_gen():
    data = ''
    while data is not None:
        print(data)
        data = yield data
    print(data)
    yield data

lst = [1, 2, 3]
it = my_gen()
next(it)  # priming the generator still needs to be done

deque(map(it.send, lst), maxlen=0)
```

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. Updated the question. This is not about nature of data being send, but about if we can do "for" (and maybe priming) in a standard function?